# How to inject logic from a function into a script element dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have a script that is added to the document dynamically and the logic I would like executed lives in a `useEffect` hook in a React component.

Here is an example of the logic:

```
const getiTunes = results => {
  if (!isMounted.current) return
  else if (results.errorMessage) throw Error(results.errorMessage)
  else setITunes(results)
}
```

and how I adding scripts to the documents:

```
const handleResults = document.createElement("script")
handleResults.type = "text/javascript"
handleResults.text = "function getItunes(response) { //type out function here as a string };"
```

Currently, I can save the results from the getItunes function to the `window` and then retrieve them in my React component, but wondering if I can somehow inject my logic directly into the script I am adding to the document.

I have tried a few things such as `handleResults.text = getiTunes` and `handleResults.text = String(getiTunes)` however neither work.

Is this possible? Or do I have to continue using something like the `window` object to pass data between the script on `document` and the React component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the underlying purpose of my script was to handle a jsonp response I found the following code from [this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j3j31qvq2v). It perfectly solves this problem by creating a function which then hands off the response to a callback function.

```
export const fetchJSONP = (url, callback) => {
  var callbackName = "jsonp_callback_" + Math.round(100000 * Math.random())
  window[callbackName] = function (data) {
    delete window[callbackName]
    document.body.removeChild(script)
    callback(data)
  }

  var script = document.createElement("script")
  script.src = url + (url.indexOf("?") >= 0 ? "&" : "?") + "callback=" + callbackName
  document.body.appendChild(script)
}
```

I then use it in the following way:

```
const handleResponse = response => {
  //do stuff with response
}
fetchJSONP("https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=98754654", handleResponse)
```